# Different alignment on Mac and Windows

Tags: javafx

[Windows](https://ibb.co/GcjMj1j)

[Mac](https://ibb.co/s9Ys55z)

As you can see, column of numbers has different alignment. This is not good.

Using different screen dimension and this problem not dimenshion, problem in different OS.

```
<VBox spacing="5.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <Label text="0">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="2">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="3">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="4">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="5">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="6">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="7">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="8">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="9">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="14.0" />
                       </font>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </Label>
                 <BorderPane.margin>
                    <Insets right="5.0" />
                 </BorderPane.margin>
              </VBox>
```

Need to fix this problem, that on Mac and Windows will the same alignment.

P.S. Also button "Cancel" on Mac looks like "Can...". This is not good too.

Comment: Using a `VBox` for the alignment won't work. A change of the default font (e.g. like the one caused by using a different os) result in different widths for the `Label`s. You need to align the text in a different way (which depends on your way of creating the grid).

Comment: Is this the full FXML?

Comment: To follow up on @fabian you probably want an 11x11 gridpane. With the 0,0 being empty, numbers and letters being the first row and column respectively, then your game table grid expanding the remaining. This way regardless of size, density or os you can align your titles appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @fabian, but how can I mark your answer as right in this comment's?

Comment: You can't. And it's not really an answer: it does not provide a solution since there is not enough info in the question to come up with a suitable solution; It's simply an explanation for the behaviour...